# Getting frame count and delay between frames from gif using javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, header, gif, frames

I am trying to know the **frame count** and **delay between frames** of a **gif** usign **javascript**,
Without actualy parsing the gif with canvas, possibly from the its **header**.

After long search in Google, which return no results,
I've tried to understand it from a **gif parsign** libraries such as 'giflib' with no success of understanding.

At the end I want to do it using **simple code I cant include library to the existed code**,
An**y other parsing tools wont be used at all**, I just look for this specific parameters

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about [jsgif](http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/)?

It allows you to parse an animated gif file with JavaScript  and add some controls to it. With some modification you can change this to a counter of how many frames your gif file has?

[image: Example of usage]

Comment: Sorry I dident mention it.
I don't want to to use library.
I am looking for simple and short code. (already managed to do it using library)

Comment: @AdiDarachi If there's a library for it then it means there _probably is no simple code_ for it.

Comment: @Jonast92 , What you are saying is actualy wrong.
The library provides lost of capabilities that I have no intention of use!. I am not familiar with the gif header struct and I am having hard time get this two parameters.
I **dont** need frames or the ability to play them, actualy anything but frame count and delay time.

Comment: @AdiDarachi : could you please mention the name of the library so that i can use it ?

Comment: @Jeffin It's mentioned at the top of the answer http://slbkbs.org/jsgif/